# A/C split unit inverter leaking. What can I do?

Tags: air-conditioning, condensation, compressor

For some unknown reason, my 12,000 BTU split unit inverter is leaking in two places. Here are the pictures of the leaks.

The A/C was thoroughly cleaned last week, and the contractor said that the A/C was in good condition. It's been leaking for a quite a while, and I thought that cleaning it would help. It didn't.

I haven't been able to contact the contractor, so I'm thinking of trying to fix it myself.

What can I do to find the source of this leak? One of the things that the contractor was supposed to do this week was replace the copper wire insulation. Could that be the issue? What else can I check?

The outdoor condenser is in the rooftop, which means that the tube runs downward toward the indoor unit.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's likely condensation, the drain tube us likely plugged or slow.  (Cooling of air produces condensation because hot air can hold more humidity than cold air).  It's a minor problem that you should be able to solve yourself, although the contractor should have checked that.

Comment: Can you take some more photos? It's difficult to tell where the leaks are coming from, since your photos are too close up (and possibly rotated?).